# What is different between chrome dev-tools and Firefox dev-tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I'm new to JavaScript and  I wrote this js code on the console :

```
function test (){} 
var a1 = new test();
 a1;//chrome dev-tool test()
 a1;// firefox dev-tool : object {}
```

and run that on **chrome dev-tool** and **Firefox dev-tool** and I saw ***different results*** .

1.in chrome : test{}
2.in Firefox: object{}

Comment: The difference is that there is no standard for what consoles would display. So any console can format objects as it sees fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chrome is essentially saying {} is an empty object that was constructed by a function with name test.Firefox is saying {} is an empty object of general construction from Object.the subtle difference is that Chrome is actively tracking ,as an internal property,the name of the actual function that did the construction , whereas other browses don t track that additional information.